# How to adjust accordion text size with the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to parse a big text file and display all the text using an accordion text effect. This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, with small text it's OK, no problem, but with a huge text...it's not working properly.

How can I add a scroll effect or make the box more big in order to show all the text content properly?

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jbfz09Ln/

The code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/accordion.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>
<body>
    <!--Añadimos al area principal el efecto acordeon con el texto -->
    <section class="mainArea" align="center">
            <button class="accordion">Boot and Services</button>
            <div id="placeholder" class="panelacc"></div>


    </section>

<script>


/* nos permite gestionar los eventos para el texto en forma de acordeon */
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (var j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
    acc[j].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

accordion.css:

```
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
}

div.panelacc {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panelacc.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}

div.panelacc.show p {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem that you have mentioned. Here is a jsfiddle created with your code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/kvc97kah/ ... can you update it and show what issue you are facing?

Comment: Run it now -> https://jsfiddle.net/kd7xnor2/ and you will see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I added some css code. Is this what you want ?

class div.panelacc:

```
border:solid 1px green;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
//max-width:200px;  // set max width
```

class .mainArea:

```
height:100%;
```

class div.panelacc.show:

```
max-height: 100%;
```

simple example:
https://jsfiddle.net/jbfz09Ln/4/

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you were doing two things wrong:

```
.mainArea{
  height:300px; /* REMOVE this one */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* AND */

div.panelacc.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  /* HERE you are setting a fix height */
}
```

Solution: remove the `height:300px;` line and change `500px` to `100%` like this `max-height: 100%;`

[check your code i have updated it](https://jsfiddle.net/kd7xnor2/1/)